# gdb backtrace shows malloc

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I am debugging process crash ,& the backtrace looks kind of like below. 
The process is crashing at different points in the code but the all the time backtrace comes down to malloc.

I tried increasing the heap from 128 M to 256 M, but that didn't help either. 
Size of the core dump is around 164 M, & while running process uses about the same virt memory.

Can you guys please point me in the right direction. 
Appreciate the help.

```
#0
#1
#2
#5  0xb7fc7966 in malloc (size=141858520)
.
.
.
#16 0x0805ef69 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffffa64)
.
```

bt 2: This is the 2nd backtrace I got. Same process but crashed at different point in code.

```
#0
#1
#2
#5  0xb7fc7677 in realloc (p=0xe01fd8, size=139629112)
.
.
.
#18 0x0805ef69 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffffa64)
```

Comment: can we see the source code?

Comment: Odds are you've corrupted memory elsewhere in your code. Most likely either (a) writing to a pointer that has been freed already, or, (b) overwriting past the end of a dynamically allocated buffer. Showing your code would help. But, odds are, the bug is not where you think it is anyway.

Comment: Did you use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to debug memory leaks? Did you compile your code with `gcc -Wall -g` (and improved it till all warnings are gone)?

Comment: Maybe valgrind can help you more than gdb in this case

Comment: You have likely overwritten the heap somewhere in your program which corrupted the heap data structures. This causes the subsequent calls to malloc/realloc fail randomly.

Comment: unfortunately , I cannot share the code. I'll give it a try with valgrind though.

Answer (score 1):

*Any* crash inside `malloc` is almost a guaranteed sign of heap corruption.

On Linux, *the* tools for finding such heap corruption are [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and [Address Sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/).

See [this page](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/ComparisonOfMemoryTools) to understand the differences between the two.